# Android: Using a primary key other than _id in update() and delete()

Tags: android, database, sqlite, primary-key

I have a table with the primary key as xyz_key_id.  I want to update a row in the table.  An example I found is :

```
db.update(DB_TABLE, values, "_id=" + rowId, null)
```

However, I would like to use a xyz_key_id as the key instead of _id.

Can I use something like:

```
String update_string = "SELECT " + xyz_key_id + " AS _id WHERE " + xyz_key_id + " = ?";

db.update(DB_TABLE, values, update_string, new String[] {key_number});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary key can be anything. `BaseColumns._ID` or "_id" is a convention that is followed which has a lot of advantages, especially when your database tables are wrapped around in by ContentProviders (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)

Comment: Originally I had "_id" as the primary key to my tables, but then needed to put the primary key from one table as a column in another table.  This made two "_id"s in the same table.

Answer (score 1):

No, in Android it has to be _id

see http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/